# What are the details of Lord Mahadeva's SarvaMedha yajna?

Tags: shiva, yajna

[Mahabharata: Santi Parva: [Rajadharmanusasana Parva:] Chapter 20](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a020.htm)

> यज्ञैरिन्द्रो विविधैरन्नवद्भि; र्देवान्सर्वानभ्ययान्महौजाः |
>
> तेनेन्द्रत्वं प्राप्य विभ्राजतेऽसौ; तस्माद्यज्ञे सर्वमेवोपयोज्यम्
> ||[११](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/unic/mbh12_sa.html)||
>
> महादेवः **सर्वमेधे** महात्मा; हुत्वात्मानं देवदेवो विभूतः |
>
> विश्वाँल्लोकान्व्याप्य विष्टभ्य कीर्त्या; विरोचते द्युतिमान्कृत्तिवासाः ||[१२](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/unic/mbh12_sa.html)||
>
> Possessed of abundant energy, Indra, by the performance of diverse sacrifices with profuse gifts of valuables, surpassed all the gods. Having got their chiefship by that means, he shineth in heaven. Therefore, everything should be applied to sacrifices. Clad in deer-skins, the high-souled Mahadeva, having poured his own self as a libation in the sacrifice called Sarva [SarvaMedha yajna], became the first of gods, and surpassing all creatures in the universe and prevailing over them by means of that achievement, shines in resplendence.

Similarly, [Mahabharata: Santi Parva: [Rajadharmanusasana Parva:] Chapter 08](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a008.htm) also mentions Lord Mahadeva's SarvaMedha yajna:

> विश्वरूपो महादेवः **सर्वमेधे** महामखे |
>
> जुहाव सर्वभूतानि तथैवात्मानमात्मना ||[३६](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/unic/mbh12_sa.html)||
>
> Mahadeva himself, of universal form, in a great sacrifice [SarvaMedha yajna] requiring libations of all kinds of flesh, poured all creatures as sacrificial libations and then his own self.

**Is there any detailed description available for Lord Mahadeva's SarvaMedha yajna?** Something like [Lord Brahma's SarvaMedha yajna](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21974/12304) description.